# Retrieving Web Site Configuration Settings from Azure for use in a Console App

Tags: c#, azure, console-application, azure-configuration

I'm trying to get the settings and connection strings from an Azure web site for use in an internal console tool.  This is proving much more difficult than I would have expected.  I'm tempted to start looking into bypassing the C# SDK altogether and just use an `HttpClient`, but I'm not quite there yet.

This is what I have so far:

```cs
var armClient = new ArmClient(new DefaultAzureCredential(), "[My subscription ID]");
var webApp = armClient.GetWebSiteResource(new Azure.Core.ResourceIdentifier("[my resource identifier]"));
var b = webApp.GetAllConfigurationData();
var c = b.First();
Console.WriteLine(c.Name);
Console.WriteLine(c.ConnectionStrings == null ? "null" : c.ConnectionStrings.Count);
Console.WriteLine(c.AppSettings == null ? "null" : c.AppSettings.Count);
```

What I'm getting is the following:

> [the correct name of the website]
> null
> null

Settings and connection strings definitely exist; I can see them on the config page for the website in Azure Portal.

The (extremely minimal and somewhat placeholderish) documentation for `GetAllConfigurationData` suggests that multiple calls and iterations may be needed, but I'm not even sure what to do with that.

Anyone have any ideas here?  Am I going about this all wrong and there's a better way?  The console app is non-negotiable, unfortunately.

---

**EDIT:** Adding a screenshot of where in the portal the config settings I'm looking at are. (Highlighted one at the bottom.)

[image: Location in Portal Nav]

Also, if it helps, I'm looking for the programmatic equivalent of this Powershell command:

`az webapp config appsettings list --name foo --resource-group bar`

Comment: Can you please share your configuration settings in Portal.

Comment: @Harshitha can you be a bit more specific on what you're looking for?  Obviously I can't give you the settings I'm actually looking for, but I might be able to provide what you need.

Comment: `I can see them on the config page for the website in Azure Portal.` what are the configuration you have and what your are trying to retrieve ?

Comment: Oh, I see.  If I go to the actual web app in Portal (not the Configuration resource, the actual web app resource), there is a section on the left that says "Configuration", along with all the normal overview, identity, and other navigation sections for the actual website.  Those are the settings I'm trying to get.  (If this still isn't clear I'll update the post.)

Comment: Yes,even Iam asking about those settings, can you share the screen cap of that by masking the values.

Comment: `the config settings are in the web page config,` And also share these config as well

Comment: @Harshitha I've shared about all I can in an edit on the original post.  Hope this helps!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256917/discussion-between-harshitha-and-ari-roth).

Answer (score 0):

I get a similar non result with "GetAllConfigurationDataAsync" but the code below, using other methods of the WebsiteResource class, works for me:

```
var armClient = host.Services.GetRequiredService<ArmClient>();
var resource = new ResourceIdentifier(resourceId);
var website = armClient.GetWebSiteResource(resource);
var connectionStrings = await website.GetConnectionStringsAsync();
foreach (var prop in connectionStrings.Value.Properties)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{prop.Key}:{prop.Value.Value}");
}
var applicationSettings = await website.GetApplicationSettingsAsync();
foreach (var appSetting in applicationSettings.Value.Properties)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{appSetting.Key}:{appSetting.Value}");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To retrieve configuration settings from Azure for use in a console application, you can utilize Azure App Configuration service. Azure App Configuration is a service that enables you to centrally manage application settings and feature flags. Here's a general outline of how you can achieve this:

1. **Create an Azure App Configuration Store**: First, you need to create an Azure App Configuration store in your Azure subscription. You can do this through the Azure portal.
2. **Add Configuration Settings**: Add the configuration settings (key-value pairs) that you want to retrieve in your console application to the Azure App Configuration store.
3. **Install the Azure App Configuration Client Library**: Install the Azure App Configuration client library for .NET. You can do this using NuGet package manager. You will need to install the `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureAppConfiguration` package.
4. **Configure Access to Azure App Configuration**: Configure access to the Azure App Configuration store in your console application. This typically involves providing connection settings such as the connection string or other authentication methods.
5. **Retrieve Configuration Settings**: Use the Azure App Configuration client library in your console application to retrieve the configuration settings from the Azure App Configuration store.

Here's a simplified code example:

```cs
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureAppConfiguration;
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        
        // Add Azure App Configuration as a configuration source
        builder.AddAzureAppConfiguration(options =>
        {
            options.Connect("<your-connection-string>")
                   .ConfigureKeyVault(kv =>
                   {
                       kv.SetCredential(new DefaultAzureCredential());
                   });
        });

        IConfigurationRoot configuration = builder.Build();

        // Retrieve configuration settings
        string setting1 = configuration["Setting1"];
        string setting2 = configuration["Setting2"];

        Console.WriteLine($"Setting1: {setting1}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Setting2: {setting2}");
    }
}
```

Replace `<your-connection-string>` with the connection string of your Azure App Configuration store.

In this example, `Setting1` and `Setting2` are the keys of the configuration settings you want to retrieve. You can add more settings as needed. Once retrieved, you can use these settings in your console application as required.

Comment: Could you confirm that this was not written by AI tools?

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't answer the question.  I specifically mentioned that the config settings are in the web page config, not the Configuration store.  They're separate things, with separate CLI commands to retrieve.

Comment: `that the config settings are in the web page config, not the Configuration store` what does that mean ?